# put a class in a list. python

Tags: python, class, list

i have to write a class which in that class can addShapes

heres the class I have to do

```
class Drawing(Circle, Square):
    list = []

    def addShape(self, theShape, colour, x, y, side):
        self.list  += [self.theShape(colour, x, y, side)]

    def display(self):
        return self.list

    def move(self):

    def changeColour(self, newColour):

    def totalArea(self):
        return
```

the shape classes:

```
class Shape(Point):

    def __init__(self, colour, x, y):
            Point.__init__(self, x, y)
            self.colour = colour
            self.centrePoint = (x,y)

    def centre(self):
        return self.centrePoint 

    def movePoint(self, newX, newY):
            Point.move(self, newX, newY)
            self.centrePoint = (self.x, self.y)


class Circle(Shape):

    def __init__(self, colour, x, y, radius):
        Shape.__init__(self, colour, x, y)
        self.radius = radius

    def getArea(self):
        return math.pi * (self.radius * self.radius)
```

plus a square class.

how do you add colour etc. plus class name of the shape into a list so then it can be used.
or whats the best way of doing this.

thanks

Comment: What does `addShapes` mean? Do you just want a list of `Shape` instances? Do you need to know what kind of shape the instance is or just call `draw()` on it and let the instance know how to do that?

Comment: Please work on the clarity of your question. It would really help to get good answers.

Comment: ive added the class  i have to do

Comment: 1) list is a built-in function, I suggest using a different variable name, 2) it's a mutable class variable, it should be created in `__init__` so it is an instance variable, 3) I use mylist.append() instead of adding a list of one, 4) move and changeColour need a pass in them, and totalArea should probably use a pass intead of an empty return (I tend to leave out return, rather than using an empty return).

Comment: How is a Drawing a Circle or a Square, which in turn is a Shape? How is a Shape a Point?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's totally clear what you're trying to accomplish, but here's what I think:

1. You should show us what you have written so far
2. You should mark it as homework if it is homework
3. You can add anything to a list in Python, so just give it a shot:

   myList = [circle_instance, CircleClass, 'some-color', 1337]

Note that I can have instances of my shapes, classes, text, integers, whatever I want in a list.

Answer (score 0):

Provided I am understanding your question correctly, you can simply place instances of your classes into the list:

```
l = [Circle(BLACK, 0.0, 0.0, 12.0), Circle(GREEN, 10.0, 0.0, 3.0), Square(YELLOW, 5.0, 5.0, 1.0)]
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you want to subclass Circle and Square. Try this:

```
class Drawing(object):
    list = []

    def addShape(self, theShape, colour, x, y, side):
        self.list  += [theShape(colour, x, y, side)]

    def display(self):
        return self.list

    def move(self):

    def changeColour(self, newColour):

    def totalArea(self):
        return
```

and then you can do something like this:

```
d = Drawing()
d.addShape(Circle, c1, 0, 0, 5)
```

If you're wanting to look up the colors based on the name (as a string), that would be doable, but there would be several different strategies.